# Exporting GraphicsRow as pdf

Tags: plotting

I am trying to save a combined `Graphics` as a pdf.

I am using the `MaTeX`package from [here](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) to use `TeX`.

```
\[Mu] = 1;
fBE[En_, T_] := 1/(Exp[(En - \[Mu])/T] - 1)
fFD[En_, T_] := 1/(Exp[(En - \[Mu])/T] + 1)
fBoltz[En_, T_] := Exp[-(En - \[Mu])/T]

p1 = Plot[
  Evaluate[{fBE[En, T], fFD[En, T], fBoltz[En, T]} /. T -> 3], {En, 
   0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 5}}, 
  AxesLabel -> MaTeX /@ {"E/\\mu", "f"}, BaseStyle -> texStyle, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[
     MaTeX /@ {"\\text{Bose-Einstein}", "\\text{Fermi-Dirac}", 
       "\\text{Maxwell-Boltzmann}"}, 
     LegendLabel -> MaTex /@ "Distribution statistics", 
     LegendLayout -> {"Row", 3}], {0.7, 0.7}]]

p2 = Plot[
  Evaluate[{fBE[En, T], fFD[En, T], fBoltz[En, T]} /. 
    T -> 0.05], {En, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, 
  AxesLabel -> MaTeX /@ {"E/\\mu", "f"}, BaseStyle -> texStyle]

p3 = Plot[
   Evaluate[{fBE[En, T], fFD[En, T], fBoltz[En, T]} /. 
     T -> 0.001], {En, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, 
   AxesLabel -> MaTeX /@ {"E/\\mu", "f"}, BaseStyle -> texStyle] // 
  Quiet

a = GraphicsRow[{p1, p2, p3}]

Export[FileNameJoin[{ParentDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]], "figures", 
   "distributions.pdf"}], a]
```

But when I open the pdf file it looks like this:

[image]

Any idea why?